# history handling in AMP pages using AMP.goBack and AMP.pushState

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I have a popup form that needs to be closed on browser back. but the problem is i just want to close the form and not go back to the previous values of the states.
for example:
lets say I have a form `Basic Details` with fields `Name, Age, Mobile`: the user sets the data
i have another state `isDataAvailable`: used to keep track if the user has already filled the data
and a field `IsBasicDetailsPopUpShown`: flag to show the popup

Initially the states will be :

```
{'name':"",'age':"",'mobile':"","isDataAvailable":false,"isBasicDetailsPopUpShown":false}
```

when i want to show the popup, I use AMP.PushState

```
{'name':"",'age':"",'mobile':"","isDataAvailable":false,"isBasicDetailsPopUpShown":true}
```

and then when the user fills the data i use AMP.setState

```
{'name':"dummy",'age':"10",'mobile':"999234234","isDataAvailable":true,"isBasicDetailsPopUpShown":true}
```

now when the user clicks on browser back i want only the 'isBasicDetailsPopUpShown' to be set to false

now on browser back the history will be poped out and will result in

```
{'name':"",'age':"",'mobile':"","isDataAvailable":false,"isBasicDetailsPopUpShown":false}
```

thus losing the data. Is there anyway to get around it?